# What is the Best practice to install sharepoint 2010 for an Extranet deployment?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What are the accounts and roles required in order to successfully install sharepoint 2010 server enterprise edn. in order to deploy an extranet successfully. 
Please do share good links that detail the same.

---

Update:

Thanks for the links. If it helps narrow it down:

- I have a sharepoint server in a DMZ(public domain) and the SQL2008 server in the local domain.I do not really know as to what kind of topology this constitutes.
- In addition I just need to create a web app and extend it to to use FBA in order to expose it to customers.

Hopefully you might be able to narrow down your advise based off of this.

Comment: I've converted this to a wiki since it is a good question but can't be definitively answered. As @Robert mentioned, this is a huge topic that depends a lot on your requirements.

Comment: @KitMenke I have posted a comment giving the details of my requirements if it helps narrow it down. Thanks

Comment: I edited your comment into your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is such a broad topic it is going to be very difficult to provide you with any guidance other than suggesting resources because it depends a lot on your requirements for things such as  performance and security so giving you any advice is very difficult. So here is a list of resources that can help you find the answers you need.

- [SharePoint 2010 Best Practices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850682.aspx) This is really where I would start as it has links to best practices for nearly every aspect of installing SharePoint.
- [Best practices for extranet environments](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204611.aspx)
- [Configure Kerberos authentication for SharePoint 2010 Products](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829837.aspx)
- [Configuring Kerberos authentication: Step-by-step configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502599.aspx)
- [Kerberos the Difinitive Guide](http://books.google.com/books/about/Kerberos.html?id=dGMd-uay-lkC)
- [The Kerberos Network Authentication Service (V5)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt)
- [SharePoint 2010 Technical diagrams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2010 Service Accounts Ref Guide](http://www.ericharlan.com/Moss_SharePoint_2007_Blog/sharepoint-2010-service-account-reference-guide-a184.html)

Answer (score 4):

Todd Klindt has a couple of good guides about [accounts](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=237) and [installation](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=320)